# external xaml resource not found by designer when referenced from control template

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have external library libccc with its own resources defined like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ccc="clr-namespace:libccc"
    >
    <ccc:BooleanToHiddenVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToHiddenVisibilityConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In my main project I include it using ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries in main app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/libccc;component/Resources/Converters.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now my problem is that when I reference that resource **from Control template only** like this:

```
<window style="{StaticResource MyDialog}">

</window>
```

where style is defined in application like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="MyDialog" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding UpdateResultDescription}" Visibility="{Binding UpdateEnded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToHiddenVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary
```

VisualStudio Designer throws exception:

> Exception: Cannot find resource named 'BooleanToHiddenVisibilityConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive.

My application works as expected, but designer throws exception. When I reference my libccc in other windows that do not use control template then designer works fine.

Anyone can give me a hint what can I change to make designer work?

Comment: In Application.xaml, are you merging the external resource dictionary into the resource dictionary where the ControlTemplate is defined? I'm wondering if the designer thinks the StaticResource is out-of-scope or something.

Could you add your entire app.xaml file to clarify this, instead of just snippets?

Comment: I updated my question so it is now more clear that I merge libccc resources in app.xaml

Comment: Sorry man, but I'm not observing this exception when I do your scenario! :/ Is libccc from a loose assembly reference, or is it a project-to-project reference?

Comment: It is a project-to-project reference. Added to solution using add->existing project.

Comment: Ever resolve this? I'm getting the same issue, out of the blue with a project that's been working for months.